# How to get all ip attached to compute using python oci

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I want to  use python  oci  package to get information about environment.
how to list all IPs addresses (both public or private) attached to compute node?
list_instances() does not provide this part of compute details unfortunately.
thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested

Comment: [This oci-python-sdk example](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/get_all_instance_ip_addresses_and_dns_info.py) should help you.

Comment: I run this command but there is no ip specified for compute instance
`instances = oci.core.ComputeClient(config).list_instances(compartment_id=compartment_id).data
print(instances)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code. Basically you have to lookup VNIC Attachment object and filter VNIC_ID based on InstanceId. VNIC_ID can be used for looking up IP Addresses subsequently.

I have used data[0] to indicate the first attachment. You could use a loop to go through all attachments and print the IP.

```
    compute_client = oci.core.ComputeClient(config={}, signer=signer)
    network_client = oci.core.VirtualNetworkClient(
        config={}, signer=signer)
    vnic_id = compute_client.list_vnic_attachments(
        cd_compartment_id, instance_id=instanceId).data[0].vnic_id
    private_ip = network_client.get_vnic(vnic_id).data.private_ip
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the *display name* of an [OCI compute instance](https://cloud.oracle.com/compute/instances) and you need its private and public IP addresses, provided that you already created an [API key](https://cloud.oracle.com/identity/domains/my-profile/api-keys) in your [profile](https://cloud.oracle.com/identity/domains/my-profile) and that you configured your [`~/.oci/config`](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm) with valid pem private key downloaded when creating the API Key, the following Python code can help:

```py
import oci

display_name = "your display name"

config = oci.config.from_file()
identity = oci.identity.IdentityClient(config)
user = identity.get_user(config["user"]).data
instances = oci.core.ComputeClient(config).list_instances(
    compartment_id=user.compartment_id).data
instance_id = {i.display_name: i.id for i in instances}[display_name]
compute_client = oci.core.ComputeClient(config)
vnic_data = compute_client.list_vnic_attachments(
    compartment_id=user.compartment_id, instance_id=instance_id).data
network_client = oci.core.VirtualNetworkClient(config)
vnic_list = [network_client.get_vnic(vnic_attachment.vnic_id).data
    for vnic_attachment in vnic_data]
public_ip = {i.display_name: i.public_ip for i in vnic_list}[display_name]
private_ip = {i.display_name: i.private_ip for i in vnic_list}[display_name]
print(public_ip, private_ip)
```

This implies:

```sh
pip3 install oci oci-cli
```

Comment: Thanks for script that helped me to extract public, private ip for instances

Answer (score 1):

As shared by @Char above, this [oci-python-sdk example](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/get_all_instance_ip_addresses_and_dns_info.py) should help you here.

You can find a list of all supported services by SDK for Python here - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/pythonsdk.htm

Additionally, full documentation for OCI Python SDK can be found here - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.21.5/